# How do I enable vertical scrolling inside the compose modalBottomSheet and disable the event that the bottomSheet closes?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet, vertical-scrolling

```
    val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
        skipPartiallyExpanded = true,
        confirmValueChange = {
            true
        }
    )

    ModalBottomSheet(
        sheetState = sheetState,
        content = {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                    .padding(10.dp)
            ) {
                content()
            }
        }
    )
```

Vertical scrolling is possible when the code is written as follows, but there is a problem that the bottom sheet closes when scrolling to the bottom

How do I make sure the bottom sheet doesn't close and allow vertical scrolling??
Blocking the drag event itself won't close the bottom sheet to the bottom scroll, but you can't scroll vertically either.
I didn't find a way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider using a [`BottomSheetScaffold`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#BottomSheetScaffold(kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.material3.BottomSheetScaffoldState,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,kotlin.Function1)). It offers a parameter called `sheetSwipeEnabled`, where you can set whether you can expand or collapse the BottomSheet by swiping. This attribute seems not to be available with a `ModalBottomSheet`.

You can try the following code:

```
val scaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState()
val scrolLState = rememberScrollState()

val endReached by remember {
    derivedStateOf {
        scrollState.value == scrollState.maxValue
    }
}

BottomSheetScaffold(
    scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
    sheetPeekHeight = 128.dp,
    sheetSwipeEnabled = !scaffoldState.bottomSheetState.hasExpandedState || endReached,
    sheetContent = {
        Box(
            Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(128.dp),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Text("Swipe up to expand sheet")
        }
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .verticalScroll(scrollState)
                .padding(10.dp)
        ) {
            content()
        }
    }
) { innerPadding ->
    // some Scaffold content
}
```

This should result in the following behavior:

- As long as the BottomSheet is fully expanded, swipe events to close the BottomSheet are ignored.
- All scroll inputs should be consumed by the scrollable Column.
- When the BottomSheet is expanded, the swipe to close the BottomSheet only will be enabled once you have scrolled to the end of the nested scrollable list.

You can programmatically expand or hide the BottomSheet by calling

```
scaffoldState.bottomSheetState.expand() 
scaffoldState.bottomSheetState.hide()
```

Comment: If you specify sheetPeekHeight as LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp.dp, it's set to full screen height and works perfectly. Thank you!